# Make MongoDB dump to specific db version

Tags: mongodb, backwards-compatibility, mongodump

My MongoDB 3.2. import does not work when I try to import a dump exported from by MongoDB 3.6.
Is there a way of using "mongodump" to export to be compatible to MongoDB 3.2.

Comment: What is the error message you get when trying to restore your MongoDB 3.6 dump into 3.2?

Answer (score 1):

Usually MongoDB suggest to not dump/restore between clusters having more than one major version apart.

What you could do is restore your dump from MongoDB 3.6, restore it to a MongoDB 3.4 and then dump it again fom 3.4 to finally restore to to MongoDB 3.2.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41844502/5945338

Usually there are incompatibilities with more than 1 major versions, please try to upgrade your MongoDB 3.2 if possible, otherwise you might need to automate the 3.4 transition part.

Comment: Dumping & restoring between different server release series is different than mixing major server versions in a replica set (which is the scenario that is not supported/tested outside of upgrades/downgrades between adjacent major versions).